# Proguard obfuscation keeps crashing my app

Tags: android, proguard

The application in question works fine without obfuscation, but once Proguard has its way with it, every time the app crashes with these logs:

> I/dalvikvm(26697): Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.d.a
>   W/dalvikvm(26697): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 756: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
>   D/dalvikvm(26697): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000b
>   I/dalvikvm(26697): Could not find method android.app.Notification$Builder.setLocalOnly, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.d.c
>   W/dalvikvm(26697): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 585: Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setLocalOnly (Z)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;

followed by a stacktrace. Here are also my rules:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations   !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*,!code/allocation/variable

-keep class android.content.pm.PackageInstaller
-keepclassmembers class * {
public PackageInstaller getPackageInstaller();
}
-keep class android.content.pm.PackageInstaller$SessionInfo
-keep class android.content.pm.PackageManager

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application

-dontwarn javax.annotation.**

-dontwarn com.google.**

-dontwarn **CompatHoneycomb
-dontwarn **CompatHoneycombMR2
-dontwarn **CompatCreatorHoneycombMR2

-dontwarn org.ietf.jgss.**

-dontwarn java.awt.**,javax.security.**,java.beans.**

-dontwarn javax.xml.stream.**

-dontwarn com.jcraft.jzlib.ZStream

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet,         int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
public static **[] values();
public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
public static <fields>;
}

-keep class net.sqlcipher.** {
*;
}

-keep class net.sqlcipher.database.** {
*;
}
```

Keeping the PackageInstaller or the mythical getPackageInstaller method didn't help with the issue at all, I also tried explicitly adding the android support library here as was suggested in another post, but that didn't help as well. If anyone has any other ideas, please share :)

EDIT:

Here's the stack trace as requested:

```
D/dalvikvm(29096): No JNI_OnLoad found in libnativehelper.so 0x0, skipping init
D/dalvikvm(29096): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 180 unimplemented (abstract) methods
D/AndroidRuntime(29096): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
D/AndroidRuntime(29096): Shutting down VM
D/COUNTRIES(29064): init: 0
D/AndroidRuntime(29064): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(29064): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415dace0)
D/audio_hw_primary(  268): out_standby: enter: stream (0xb758f388) usecase(1: low-latency-playback)
D/hardware_info(  268): hw_info_append_hw_type : device_name = speaker-cdp
F/libc    (29064): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000008 (code=1), thread 29104 (pool-1-thread-1)
I/DEBUG   (25488): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (25488): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/hltexx/hlte:4.4.2/KOT49H/N9005XXUENC2:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   (25488): Revision: '8'
I/DEBUG   (25488): pid: 29064, tid: 29104, name: pool-1-thread-1  >>> com.mobility.client <<<
I/DEBUG   (25488): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000008
I/DEBUG   (25488):     r0 00000000  r1 00000002  r2 00000008  r3 768c99b8
I/DEBUG   (25488):     r4 6d4877c0  r5 00000000  r6 40246f88  r7 00000000
I/DEBUG   (25488):     r8 76710988  r9 764a09a4  sl 7648ab58  fp 7671099c
I/DEBUG   (25488):     ip 7000fb7c  sp 76710940  lr 4151dff7  pc 4151dffe  cpsr 600b0030
I/DEBUG   (25488):     d0  0000000000000000  d1  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (25488):     d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (25488):     d4  fc7cdf6f0f050ae2  d5  5acc674a23ede6f8
I/DEBUG   (25488):     d6  3407f4a06c11dbd0  d7  6bd07b75a63c3008
I/DEBUG   (25488):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (25488):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (25488):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (25488):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (25488):     d16 6f692f6176616a4c  d17 736544656c69462f
I/DEBUG   (25488):     d18 41b832a041b83190  d19 41b835a041b83408
I/DEBUG   (25488):     d20 41b8386041b836f0  d21 41b83b3041b839d0
I/DEBUG   (25488):     d22 41b83df041b83c90  d23 41b83f5041b83ea0
I/DEBUG   (25488):     d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (25488):     d26 00000000000009ba  d27 0000000000000005
I/DEBUG   (25488):     d28 0000000000000002  d29 0000000005000007
I/DEBUG   (25488):     d30 0202020202020202  d31 0000000000ffffff
I/DEBUG   (25488):     scr 20000012
I/DEBUG   (25488): 
I/DEBUG   (25488): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (25488):     #00  pc 0004cffe  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (25488):     #01  pc 00001dad  /system/lib/libnativehelper.so (jniGetFDFromFileDescriptor+80)
I/DEBUG   (25488):     #02  pc 0001d975  /system/lib/libjavacore.so
I/DEBUG   (25488):     #03  pc 0001ea10  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+116)
I/DEBUG   (25488):     #04  pc 0004f6cf  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
I/DEBUG   (25488):     #05  pc 00027ea0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (25488):     #06  pc 0002f3e4  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
I/DEBUG   (25488):     #07  pc 0002ca48  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
I/DEBUG   (25488):     #08  pc 00061de1  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+392)
I/DEBUG   (25488):     #09  pc 00069f9f  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (25488):     #10  pc 00027ea0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (25488):     #11  pc 0002f3e4  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
I/DEBUG   (25488):     #12  pc 0002ca48  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
I/DEBUG   (25488):     #13  pc 00061afd  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
I/DEBUG   (25488):     #14  pc 00061b21  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
I/DEBUG   (25488):     #15  pc 0005681b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (25488):     #16  pc 0000d1c0  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
I/DEBUG   (25488):     #17  pc 0000d358  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
I/DEBUG   (25488): 
I/DEBUG   (25488): stack:
I/DEBUG   (25488):          76710900  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (25488):          76710904  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (25488):          76710908  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (25488):          7671090c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (25488):          76710910  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (25488):          76710914  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (25488):          76710918  415851b0  
I/DEBUG   (25488):          7671091c  76710944  [stack:29104]
I/DEBUG   (25488):          76710920  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (25488):          76710924  4151baaf  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (25488):          76710928  7648ab48  
I/DEBUG   (25488):          7671092c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (25488):          76710930  768c99b8  
I/DEBUG   (25488):          76710934  6d4877c0  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (25488):          76710938  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (25488):          7671093c  4151dff7  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (25488):     #00  76710940  768c99b8  
I/DEBUG   (25488):          76710944  7648ab48  
I/DEBUG   (25488):          76710948  6d4877c0  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (25488):          7671094c  768c99b8  
I/DEBUG   (25488):          76710950  40247004  /system/lib/libnativehelper.so
I/DEBUG   (25488):          76710954  40243daf  /system/lib/libnativehelper.so (jniGetFDFromFileDescriptor+82)
I/DEBUG   (25488):     #01  76710958  00000003  
I/DEBUG   (25488):          7671095c  6d4a3890  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (25488):          76710960  768c99b8  
I/DEBUG   (25488):          76710964  00000004  
I/DEBUG   (25488):          76710968  00000003  
I/DEBUG   (25488):          7671096c  6fffb979  /system/lib/libjavacore.so
I/DEBUG   (25488):     #02  76710970  00000003  
I/DEBUG   (25488):          76710974  6d4a3890  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (25488):          76710978  7648ab48  
I/DEBUG   (25488):          7671097c  00000004  
I/DEBUG   (25488):          76710980  764a09ac  
I/DEBUG   (25488):          76710984  414efa14  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+120)
I/DEBUG   (25488): 
I/DEBUG   (25488): memory near r3:
I/DEBUG   (25488):     768c9998 61636966 0000001b 41bc1f10 400a91d0  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     768c99a8 2e707061 69746f4e 61636966 00000023  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     768c99b8 4157c498 00000000 00000010 7648ab48  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     768c99c8 00000000 768c46c8 76075fb8 0000002b  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     768c99d8 00000000 00000000 4284c6a0 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     768c99e8 00000000 7648b170 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     768c99f8 73656c69 0000006b 00540284 0c00855c  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     768c9a08 09032313 330b0301 0a0b090b 0c090a41  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     768c9a18 0a510b0b 0a0b0a61 0b0b0b0b 0b41210b  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     768c9a28 0c0bfc0b 23210b03 09090b02 4309200a  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     768c9a38 0a110913 0b0b0b0b 09130b0b 11090b0a  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     768c9a48 130a0b0a 22110923 0c1df823 0b11080b  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     768c9a58 0a09430a 010c0afd 746e650a 0000020b  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     768c9a68 415f24b0 000001e8 41bb6f58 000001d4  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     768c9a78 d1d1d1d1 d1d1d1d1 d1d1d1d1 d1d1d1d1  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     768c9a88 d1d1d1d1 d1d1d1d1 d1d1d1d1 d1d1d1d1  
I/DEBUG   (25488): 
I/DEBUG   (25488): memory near r4:
I/DEBUG   (25488):     6d4877a0 00000000 00000014 415cbd40 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     6d4877b0 415cb9f8 00000000 00000000 00000014  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     6d4877c0 415cffe0 6e67e071 6e64695b 00000002  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     6d4877d0 00000008 00000074 415cffe0 00010008  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     6d4877e0 00020000 00000001 6e63be9d 41588818  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     6d4877f0 00000929 6e67227b 6e5016a0 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     6d487800 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     6d487810 415cffe0 00010001 00020000 00010001  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     6d487820 6e63bef1 41588818 00000929 6e67227b  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     6d487830 6e501700 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     6d487840 00000000 00000000 00000000 0000011c  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     6d487850 415cffe0 00000011 0002000b 00010000  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     6d487860 6e6853af 41588818 00000030 6e64695b  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     6d487870 6e501720 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     6d487880 00000000 00000000 415cffe0 00000011  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     6d487890 0002000c 00020000 6e69a270 41588818  
I/DEBUG   (25488): 
I/DEBUG   (25488): memory near r6:
I/DEBUG   (25488):     40246f68 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     40246f78 40247098 40247050 400a9384 4024703c  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     40246f88 00000000 00000000 00000000 40083a41  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     40246f98 40083945 400b6919 40274c29 4007e281  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     40246fa8 4006e4a5 400813c9 400b6885 400b68db  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     40246fb8 400804fd 400b6927 40274c2d 4025f53b  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     40246fc8 4007cf71 4007d499 4006cf2d 40057125  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     40246fd8 40057525 400837d5 4007c7e4 400575e1  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     40246fe8 40034e19 40034e9d 40034dc9 40050b9d  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     40246ff8 40034f4d 4007d17c 40247000 00000001  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     40247008 00000001 6d487d40 6d4877c0 00000001  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     40247018 6d487810 00000001 6d4877c0 1d20004e  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     40247028 1d200072 1d200006 1d20002e 1d20001e  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     40247038 1d20008a 1d20009e 1d20006e 1d20007a  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     40247048 1d200022 1d2000c2 1d20008e 1d2000b6  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     40247058 1d2000b2 1d200052 1d20004a 1d200012  
I/DEBUG   (25488): 
I/DEBUG   (25488): memory near r8:
I/DEBUG   (25488):     76710968 00000003 6fffb979 00000003 6d4a3890  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     76710978 7648ab48 00000004 764a09ac 414efa14  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     76710988 764a09a0 00000001 6e646be6 415e2218  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     76710998 41b82ee0 415206d3 764a09a0 6e646be3  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     767109a8 6fffb96d 7648ab58 7648aeb4 415cd940  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     767109b8 00000000 00000000 415cb1e8 400a9384  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     767109c8 00000000 00000020 00000000 00000020  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     767109d8 00000000 00000020 415832c8 7648ab48  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     767109e8 41500398 00000000 76710b50 7648ab48  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     767109f8 76710a34 6d482fc8 76710b34 415003e8  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     76710a08 41b85b10 00000000 415832c8 400a9384  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     76710a18 00000020 415832c8 41500398 414fda4c  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     76710a28 00000000 00000000 00000000 6e519748  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     76710a38 764a0ae0 6d479370 6e793000 415d37e0  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     76710a48 768c99b8 76710c40 00000000 76710c94  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     76710a58 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (25488): 
I/DEBUG   (25488): memory near r9:
I/DEBUG   (25488):     764a0984 00000000 00000000 764a09c0 6e5e1adc  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     764a0994 6d4a3890 00000000 00000000 1f600001  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     764a09a4 00000000 00000003 764a09e4 6e5e47cc  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     764a09b4 6d4b76a0 6e5e1adc 00000000 415e2218  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     764a09c4 415e2208 00000000 00000003 764a0a18  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     764a09d4 6e5e3638 6d5ba7f0 6e5e47cc 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     764a09e4 764a0a18 6e4f3846 415e2208 00000003  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     764a09f4 00000000 41b7ca28 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     764a0a04 764a0a60 6e5e34f4 6d58ea98 6e5e3638  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     764a0a14 00000000 6d58cc88 41b7cc08 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     764a0a24 00000000 00000000 00000002 00000002  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     764a0a34 41b84710 00000001 00000000 41b797e0  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     764a0a44 000001bb 00004e20 764a0a94 6e537766  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     764a0a54 6d58ea28 6e5e34f4 00000000 764a0a94  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     764a0a64 6e537730 6d789b00 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     764a0a74 41b797e0 000001bb 00004e20 764a0ac0  
I/DEBUG   (25488): 
I/DEBUG   (25488): memory near sl:
I/DEBUG   (25488):     7648ab38 00000000 00000000 00000070 0000045b  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     7648ab48 6e537d24 764a09a0 6d4b76a0 6e793000  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     7648ab58 00000000 768c99b8 76710ab8 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     7648ab68 76710b0c 00000010 00000000 414efb80  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     7648ab78 00000000 00000000 6c84a770 7649d300  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     7648ab88 00000000 00000000 00000001 00004000  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     7648ab98 00000000 7648b1b8 414efb80 414f4ac0  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     7648aba8 00000000 414f8bbc 414f8c30 414f8ae0  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     7648abb8 414f8b00 414f8b5c 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     7648abc8 764ba780 00000028 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     7648abd8 00000000 00000000 00002000 415839fc  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     7648abe8 00000000 00000000 00000001 7648b400  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     7648abf8 00000001 00000040 00000200 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     7648ac08 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     7648ac18 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     7648ac28 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (25488): 
I/DEBUG   (25488): memory near fp:
I/DEBUG   (25488):     7671097c 00000004 764a09ac 414efa14 764a09a0  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     7671098c 00000001 6e646be6 415e2218 41b82ee0  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     7671099c 415206d3 764a09a0 6e646be3 6fffb96d  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     767109ac 7648ab58 7648aeb4 415cd940 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     767109bc 00000000 415cb1e8 400a9384 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     767109cc 00000020 00000000 00000020 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     767109dc 00000020 415832c8 7648ab48 41500398  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     767109ec 00000000 76710b50 7648ab48 76710a34  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     767109fc 6d482fc8 76710b34 415003e8 41b85b10  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     76710a0c 00000000 415832c8 400a9384 00000020  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     76710a1c 415832c8 41500398 414fda4c 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     76710a2c 00000000 00000000 6e519748 764a0ae0  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     76710a3c 6d479370 6e793000 415d37e0 768c99b8  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     76710a4c 76710c40 00000000 76710c94 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     76710a5c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     76710a6c 00000000 00000000 00000018 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (25488): 
I/DEBUG   (25488): memory near ip:
I/DEBUG   (25488):     7000fb5c 40209ef0 402084e4 4020a014 4020a100  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     7000fb6c 402088c0 4020e3cc 402105a8 4020e594  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     7000fb7c 40243d5d 4007b354 4020e820 4086b471  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     7000fb8c 4086c1a1 406c2e71 406c258d 406b1dcd  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     7000fb9c 406cb429 4086cbf9 4086b4d9 4086b479  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     7000fbac 4009586c 406d2e0d 4085f501 407f0c91  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     7000fbbc 406d2dd5 40860f79 4082a6d5 406b3115  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     7000fbcc 40244dbb 406b3111 4084c671 406cd369  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     7000fbdc 406cd095 406c7f3d 4069fd81 406a001d  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     7000fbec 4068de21 4068dd1d 406b30f9 406b3101  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     7000fbfc 406f439d 408771dd 4007d499 406d4911  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     7000fc0c 406d4b5d 406d4661 406d47b9 406c7a4d  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     7000fc1c 406c8d41 406c7dad 4084c299 407bf099  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     7000fc2c 407bd7e5 406ed3cd 406ed2d1 4069a1dd  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     7000fc3c 4084b3d5 4084c361 406d5fad 4069e735  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     7000fc4c 4069ec8d 4069ff55 4069fbed 4069e7c9  
I/DEBUG   (25488): 
I/DEBUG   (25488): memory near sp:
I/DEBUG   (25488):     76710920 00000000 4151baaf 7648ab48 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     76710930 768c99b8 6d4877c0 00000000 4151dff7  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     76710940 768c99b8 7648ab48 6d4877c0 768c99b8  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     76710950 40247004 40243daf 00000003 6d4a3890  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     76710960 768c99b8 00000004 00000003 6fffb979  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     76710970 00000003 6d4a3890 7648ab48 00000004  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     76710980 764a09ac 414efa14 764a09a0 00000001  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     76710990 6e646be6 415e2218 41b82ee0 415206d3  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     767109a0 764a09a0 6e646be3 6fffb96d 7648ab58  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     767109b0 7648aeb4 415cd940 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     767109c0 415cb1e8 400a9384 00000000 00000020  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     767109d0 00000000 00000020 00000000 00000020  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     767109e0 415832c8 7648ab48 41500398 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     767109f0 76710b50 7648ab48 76710a34 6d482fc8  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     76710a00 76710b34 415003e8 41b85b10 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     76710a10 415832c8 400a9384 00000020 415832c8  
I/DEBUG   (25488): 
I/DEBUG   (25488): code around pc:
I/DEBUG   (25488):     4151dfdc 4603bd30 460db537 4619a801 f7fd4614  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     4151dfec 4629fd43 f7fe9801 68e1fd7b f0116922  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     4151dffc 58840f40 f3bfd001 a8018f5f fd5cf7fd  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     4151e00c bd3e4620 b5374603 a801460d 46144619  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     4151e01c fd2af7fd 98014629 fd62f7fe 692268e1  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     4151e02c 0f40f011 5880d004 8f5ff3bf e000b284  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     4151e03c a8015a84 fd40f7fd bd3eb220 b5374603  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     4151e04c a801460d 46144619 fd0ef7fd 98014629  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     4151e05c fd46f7fe 692268e1 0f40f011 5880d004  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     4151e06c 8f5ff3bf e000b284 a8015a84 fd24f7fd  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     4151e07c bd3e4620 b5374603 a801460d 46144619  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     4151e08c fcf2f7fd 98014629 fd2af7fe 692268e1  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     4151e09c 0f40f011 5880d004 8f5ff3bf e000b2c4  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     4151e0ac a8015c84 fd08f7fd bd3eb260 b5374603  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     4151e0bc a801460d 46144619 fcd6f7fd 98014629  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     4151e0cc fd0ef7fe 692268e1 0f40f011 5880d003  
I/DEBUG   (25488): 
I/DEBUG   (25488): code around lr:
I/DEBUG   (25488):     4151dfd4 4620fd77 b0034629 4603bd30 460db537  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     4151dfe4 4619a801 f7fd4614 4629fd43 f7fe9801  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     4151dff4 68e1fd7b f0116922 58840f40 f3bfd001  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     4151e004 a8018f5f fd5cf7fd bd3e4620 b5374603  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     4151e014 a801460d 46144619 fd2af7fd 98014629  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     4151e024 fd62f7fe 692268e1 0f40f011 5880d004  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     4151e034 8f5ff3bf e000b284 a8015a84 fd40f7fd  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     4151e044 bd3eb220 b5374603 a801460d 46144619  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     4151e054 fd0ef7fd 98014629 fd46f7fe 692268e1  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     4151e064 0f40f011 5880d004 8f5ff3bf e000b284  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     4151e074 a8015a84 fd24f7fd bd3e4620 b5374603  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     4151e084 a801460d 46144619 fcf2f7fd 98014629  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     4151e094 fd2af7fe 692268e1 0f40f011 5880d004  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     4151e0a4 8f5ff3bf e000b2c4 a8015c84 fd08f7fd  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     4151e0b4 bd3eb260 b5374603 a801460d 46144619  
I/DEBUG   (25488):     4151e0c4 fcd6f7fd 98014629 fd0ef7fe 692268e1  
W/ActivityManager(  736):   Force finishing activity com.mobility.client/.newui.activities.LoginActivity
D/Zygote  (  266): Process 29064 terminated by signal (11)
I/WindowState(  736): WIN DEATH: Window{41f4dc08 u0 com.mobility.client/com.mobility.client.newui.activities.LoginActivity}
W/ActivityManager(  736): Exception thrown during pause
W/ActivityManager(  736): android.os.DeadObjectException
W/ActivityManager(  736):   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  736):   at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.schedulePauseActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:660)
W/ActivityManager(  736):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startPausingLocked(ActivityStack.java:765)
W/ActivityManager(  736):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2497)
W/ActivityManager(  736):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2374)
W/ActivityManager(  736):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2078)
W/ActivityManager(  736):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppCrashLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:9736)
W/ActivityManager(  736):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.makeAppCrashingLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:9629)
W/ActivityManager(  736):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.crashApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:10280)
W/ActivityManager(  736):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:9825)
W/ActivityManager(  736):   at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run(NativeCrashListener.java:86)
```

EDIT 2:
Here's the build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

import com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.0'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.2'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':libsuperuser')
    compile files('libs/guava-r09.jar')
    compile files('libs/sqlcipher.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/bugsense3.1.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0'
    compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.9.jar')
    compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    compile files('libs/mail.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsch-0.1.51.jar')
    compile files('libs/splunk-mint-4.2-javadoc.jar')
    compile files('libs/splunk-mint-4.2.jar')
}

android {
    signingConfigs {
        if (System.getenv('PROPER_SIGNED')) {
            debug {
                /* deleted keystore stuff for this post */
            }
        } else {
            debug {
                if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
                    storeFile file('D:\\Work\\debug.keystore')
                } else {
                    storeFile file('/home/keystore/debug.keystore')
                }
            }
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        pickFirst 'META-INF/services/com.kenai.jbosh.HTTPSender'
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-project.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

android {
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
    compileSdkVersion 22

    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}

task copyNativeLibs(type: Copy) {
    from(new File(project(':').projectDir, 'libs')) { include '**/*.so' }
    into new File(buildDir, 'native-libs')
}

// Whenever the code is compiled, also copy the native libs to the build folder
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) { compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn copyNativeLibs }

// On "gradle clean" also reverse the copying of the native libraries
clean.dependsOn 'cleanCopyNativeLibs'

// Include the native-libs folder into the final APK
tasks.withType(PackageApplication) { pkgTask ->
    pkgTask.jniFolders = [new File(buildDir, 'native-libs')]
}
```

Comment: Warnings you have posted are irrelevant. Post the stacktrace, that follows.

Comment: Post your `build.gradle`.

Comment: @JaredBurrows Thanks, but can you be a little more specific on what you want to take a look at, because otherwise my post would get quite lengthy.

Comment: 1. You should cut back on your dependencies and focus on removing multidex. guava and gson can be converted to gradle. nineoldandroids is deprecated. 2. Are you showing `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-project.txt')` or this file `'proguard-rules.pro'`? The Android proguard that comes with the Android SDK should easily take care of your issue.

Comment: Thanks, I've removed multidex (it was a temporary experiment for another issue), I've listed my proguard-rules.pro contents right below the crash logs at the top of the post, and my proguard-project.txt file contains nothing but the default commented out text Android Studio creates it with. And I am using Android Studio, what do you mean by saying the proguard that comes with the Android SDK can take care of my issue?

Comment: hey !!! you found any solution for this ?

Comment: Sorry, not a satisfactory one - I just severely shortened the list of obfuscated classes.

Answer (score 1):

Add this 2 lines to your rules.

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

Comment: Thanks, but the issue remains the same :(